# Floting divs around a center div (For a grid)

Tags: html, css

I want to make a div grid with a bigger center div in the middle, but the small divs won't wrap properly. What must I change? I'm trying not to use tables because of bandwith and so on.

My HTML:

```
<div id="main">

    <!-- a lot of .icon's here -->
    <div class="icon"></div>
    <div class="title"></div>
    <div class="icon"></div>
    <!-- a lot of .icon's here -->

</div>
```

My CSS:

```
#main {
  display: inline-block;
  margin: 5em 0 3em 0;
  width: 66.2em;
  height: 35.2em;
  text-align: left;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.icon {
  background: #000;
  height: 5em;
  width: 5em;
  margin: 0 0.2em 0.2em 0;
  display: inline-block;
}

.title {
  background: #777;
  height: 10.2em;
  width: 21.4em;
  margin: 0 0.2em 0.2em 0;
  display: inline-block;
}
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: What do you mean by they won't wrap properly?  What are they doing that looks wrong to you?\

Comment: Please create a jsfiddle and share the link. It'll help you getting better replies.

Comment: Seems to be working for me: http://jsfiddle.net/fx62r/

Comment: What exactly do you mean by floating elements?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here you go: **Fiddle**    http://jsfiddle.net/fx62r/2/

`inline-block` leaves white-space between elements. I would use `float: left;` instead of inline block

Write elements on same line to avoid white-space. Like this:

`<div class="icon"></div><div class="title"></div><div class="icon"></div>`

And remove Margin:

```
 .icon {
     margin: 0 0.2em 0.2em 0;  //Remove.

 }

 .title {
      margin: 0 0.2em 0.2em 0; //Remove

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
#main {
  display: inline-block;
  margin: 5em 0 3em 0;
  width: 66.2em;
  height: 35.2em;
  text-align: left;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.icon {
  background: #000;
  float:left;
  height: 5em;
  width: 5em;
  margin: 4% 0.2em 0.2em 0;
  display: inline-block;
}

.title {
  background: #777;
  height: 10.2em;
  width: 21.4em;
  margin: 0 0.2em 0 0;
  display: inline-block;
  float:left;
}
```

please see this code, i hope it will helpful.